# UK Visa Application Support Centre in the USA

Tags: visas, usa, uk

I wish to apply for a UK visa from the USA. I'm an Indian citizen with a H1B.

On the [UK gov website](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/usa-apply-for-a-uk-visa/apply-for-a-uk-visa-in-the-usa), it says I should have two options after filling in the online application form:

1. Go to a VFS Premium Application Centre (costs extra 400USD)
2. Go to an Application Support Centre to submit biometrics (free)

After I do fill in the application however, it only shows me the first option which is very expensive, i.e., VFS PAC.

Any idea why the Application Support Centres are not being listed on the uk gov website?

Comment: What kind of visa application are you submitting? Do you only see the VFS option on the page "Choose a service"?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. vote we put on hold.